# SOAP request on iPhone SDK

Tags: macos, ios, soap, iphone

I have looked at some STUB generators for iPhone SDK like wsdl2objc,sudzc. Problem is Endpoint URL is separated from WSDL . How do I proceed with that ?
(When Using SOAPUI I can manually enter ( Add or Edit ) endpoint...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up dropping idea of using code generators, instead constructed requests then used NSURLConnection methods.

Answer (score 1):

Can you manually add the endpoint in the wsdl and run the code gen ?

Comment: Thanks for reply. wsdl2objc and sudzc just gives me option to enter wsdl location and I don't see any other option, unlike SOAP UI that lets me add or edit endpoint also.